# Optimal way to get Private Working Set Memory in C# for a specific instance of a process

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi

I'm building a small console app that forcibly closes processes that use a certain amount of memory, and I'm struggling to get it properly working when the CPU is already using a lot of its power.

Whenever I use the PerformanceCounter to get the **Private Working Set** memory, I easily get into the following exception:

> One or more errors occured

It looks to me, that if I "attach" the PerformanceCounter to a process, I can no longer simply **.Kill()** it. It certainly is a slower process, even to get the values.

When I use **Task Manager** I can clearly see the memory usage of a process. If I go into the Details tab, I can see that the memory column is actually the "Private Working Set" value.

**Is there a way to get this value in a more optimal, faster way?**

Here's the code I use to get the Private Working Set via a PerformanceCounter:

```
public static long GetPrivateWorkingSetMemoryOfProcess(Process process)
{
    long process_size = 0;
    String InstanceName = PerformanceCounterInstanceName(process);
    var counter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Working Set - Private", InstanceName, true);
    process_size = Convert.ToInt32(counter.NextValue()) / 1024;
    return process_size;
}
```

Since the PerformanceCounter uses the process name as a parameter, and not the ID, I use this function to get the correct process name of a Process:

```
public static string PerformanceCounterInstanceName(this Process process)
{
    var matchesProcessId = new Func<string, bool>(instanceName =>
    {
        using (var pc = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "ID Process", instanceName, true))
        {
            if ((int)pc.RawValue == process.Id)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    });

    string processName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(process.ProcessName);
    return new PerformanceCounterCategory("Process")
           .GetInstanceNames()
           .AsParallel()
           .FirstOrDefault(instanceName => instanceName.StartsWith(processName)
                                           && matchesProcessId(instanceName));
}
```

And here's where I would use it to kill a process that has a certain amount of memory usage:

```
//get Process By ID
Process processToClose = Process.GetProcessById(Convert.ToInt32(processid));

long processesPrivateWorkingSetMemoryUsage = GetPrivateWorkingSetMemoryOfProcess(processToClose);
Console.WriteLine("Process '" + processid + "' uses " + processesPrivateWorkingSetMemoryUsage.ToString() + " memory.");
if (processesPrivateWorkingSetMemoryUsage <= 8000)
{
    processToClose.Kill()
}
```

Comment: "One or more errors occured" - This is typically an [AggregateException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception?view=netframework-4.8), which by itself is not very helpful. Make sure you inspect (and update your question accordingly) the [InnerExceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception.innerexceptions?view=netframework-4.8) property to understand what really the issue is.

Comment: One more thing: "when the CPU is already using a lot of its power" ... "It certainly is a slower process, even to get the values" don't you think that these are (naturally) related?

Comment: The optimal solution is probably, to not do any of this at all, and instead have the system enforce a hard limit by calling [SetProcessWorkingSetSizeEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-setprocessworkingsetsizeex). Depending on the system you use, there might be pre-built solutions (like [Windows System Resource Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc732553(v=ws.11))).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using API, a workaround is call the following PowerShell command in C#.

```
(Get-Counter "\Process(notepad)\Working Set - Private").CounterSamples |
    Sort-Object InstanceName |
        Format-Table InstanceName, @{Label="PrivateWorkingSet"; Expression={$_.CookedValue / 1MB}} -AutoSize
```

Here I select notepad as an example. You can call this command for each process to check the private working set.

Kill the process:

```
Stop-Process -Name "notepad"
```

Refer to "[Executing PowerShell scripts from C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/)" "[Get-Counter - Example 14:Find processes on a computer with the largest working sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-counter?view=powershell-5.1)"

Comment: Hello Rita Han!
This is a really interesting approach, but is PowerShell really more optimal/faster than C#?